# codeblocks install failed. Dependency not resolved, libgcc1

Tags: installation, dependencies

I am trying to install Codeblocks using Ubuntu Software Center. I found it but when install, I get dependency not resolved. My system Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit.

```
codeblocks:depends:libgcc1(>=1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
depends:codeblocks-common(=10.05-2) but 12.11-2 is to be installed.
```

I went to Codeblocks "more info" button in Ubuntu software center and selected all the add-ons for codeblocks.  Apply changes and now I get an additional (to the two above) dependency message:

```
depends:libwxsmithlib0(=10.05-2) but 12.11-2 is to be installed.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got for it for ubuntu adding "pasgui" to my sources...It was someone else recommendation. Thanks anyway because you helped me to know how to add and update sources.

Basically follow above instructions but instead of using cambrium I used pasgui and for details of path go to pasgui web site.

Pasgui PPA https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Add it using command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

and install codeblocks with

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (press `ctrl + alt + t`)
2. Type `gksu apt-get install codeblocks`

As far as I know, codeblocks is included in ubuntu 12.04 repository list.

Comment: What I get is: The following packages have unment dependencies: codeblocks:depends:codeblocks-common (=10.05-2) but it is not going to be installed.   It is weird because I do have the Codeblocks icon in my applications menu but it just do nothing.